# How to change prompt color in Swift 5 iOS16

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, ios16

I am trying to change the color of the prompt in my navigation controller so that it is white not black for iOS16.

[image]
The following code changes the title but not the prompt. My code is:

```
import UIKit

class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue //UIColor.lincsNavBarBlueColor()
        appearance.titleTextAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] = UIColor.white

        navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance

        navigationItem.title = "Hello there"
        navigationItem.prompt = "This is the prompt"
    }
}
```

What do I need to add to change the prompt color? Thanks.

Comment: It's probably not possible. The "prompt" has been sort of a dead letter for many years. You can't  expect to give modern commands to an ancient outmoded feature.

Comment: You might try saying `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black` but I don't really expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bug and I doubt Apple will fix it.

I've worked around it by subclassing the UINavigationController and diving for the label.

```
@objc
final class NavigationControllerWithPrompt: UINavigationController {
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        changePromptColor()
    }
    
    private func changePromptColor() {
        let promptView = navigationBar.subviews.first { view in
            return String(describing: type(of: view)) == "_UINavigationBarModernPromptView"
        }
        let promptLabel = promptView?.subviews.compactMap{ $0 as? UILabel }.first
        promptLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
}
```

Comment: How do I replace the current navigationController property that exists in UIViewController with this new navigationControllerWithPrompt?